# What is the right way to access property from another class?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I would like to access my map from walk method of my Enemy class. I'm guessing I could create an instance of GameScene, but that seems to be not a good idea.

How else I could do that?

**GameScene.m**

```
@interface GameScene : SKScene
@property (nonatomic) Map *map;
@end

@implementation GameScene


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    // map
    self.map = [Map new];
    self.map.level = 1;
    [self.map generateMap];
    [self addChild:self.map];

    // enemy
    Enemy *enemy = [Enemy new];
    [self addChild:enemy];

}
```

**Enemy.m**

```
#import "Enemy.h"

@implementation Enemy

-(instancetype) init{
  ...
}


-(void)walk{
    NSLog(@"enemy walk");   
}

@end
```

Comment: In what way do you intend to use the map from the Enemy class?

Comment: I think you need `+[GameScene sharedGameScene]`

Comment: @ZeMoon Well, I would like to use map to check if enemy can walk on that node (is it a tile, or a wall.. etc..)

Comment: Could you post the code where you add the enemy node to the scene?

Comment: @ZeMoon Take a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### So you want your Enemy to be able to retrieve a reference to the current GameScene

Once the `Enemy` has been added to your `GameScene`, you can use the `scene` property (which `Enemy` inherits from `SKNode`) to retrieve the `SKScene` where he does live.

Next you'll need to cast the `SKScene` to a `GameScene` pointer.

> The following code goes inside the `Enemy` class.

### In Swift

```
let gameScene = self.scene as? GameScene
```

### In Objective-C

```
GameScene * gameScene = (GameScene*) self.scene;
```

### Warning

If you invoke run this code inside Enemy before it has been added to your GameScene or after it has been removed, your `gameScene` will contain a `nil` value.

Comment: I'm still trying to digest your answer. But I've tried, and to my astonishment it does work! Thanks!